# Are all types extending std::is_floating_point required to implement FENV in C++11 standard?

Tags: c++11, floating-point, standards

I'm implementing a function as follows:

```
template <typename FP>
void do_something(FP f){
    static_assert(std::is_floating_point<FP>::value, "not a floating point");
    ...
}
```

In this context, any floating point can be used (native or custom, i.e. multi-precision float libraries).

I wonder if standard states anything about what to expect from types overloading the is_floating_point. Can I count for them being required to work with FENV?

Can I assume the following code should work properly if a custom floating point implementation is overloading the std::is_floating_point?

```
template <typename FP>
void do_something(FP f){
    static_assert(std::is_floating_point<FP>::value, "not a floating point");
    if (std::fetestexcept(FE_DIVBYZERO)){
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that it is legal to specialize is_floating_point for anything but float/double/long double?

Comment: Not really sure at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There ain't no such thing as a "custom floating point type", as far as `std::is_floating_point` is concerned.

> **20.10.4.1/1** The primary type categories correspond to the descriptions given in section 3.9 of the C++ standard.
>
> **Table 47** — Primary type category predicates
> `template <class T> struct is_floating_point;` `T` is a floating point type (3.9.1)
>
> **3.9.1/8** There are three *floating point types*: `float`, `double`, and `long double`.
>
> **17.6.4.2.1/1** The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it adds declarations or definitions to namespace `std` or to a namespace within namespace `std` unless otherwise specified. A program may add a template specialization for any standard library template to namespace `std` only if the declaration depends on a user-defined type and the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template and is not explicitly prohibited.

Comment: [meta.type.synop]/p1: "The behavior of a program that adds specializations for any of the class templates defined in this subclause is undefined unless otherwise specified."